# Como manter um item de uma controller em parte estática da pagina?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

É o seguinte galera, tenho uma pagina do projeto que serve como padrão para todas as outras, um Layout.. Porém desejo adicionei um item (informativos) nela, e ela só permanece na página inicial e no CRUD dos informativos, quando vai para outras páginas que ocorre a troca de controller, dá erro e os informativos somem. Alguém poderia ajudar??

página de layout:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="c-slide" class="carousel slide auto panel">

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php foreach ($informativos as $index => $informativo){ ?>

                <div class="item text-center<?php echo ($index === 0 ? " active" : "") ?>" style="width: 90%;margin-left:5%">
                    <div class="alert alert-block alert-<?php echo $informativo['Informativo']['tipo']; ?> fade in">                                    
                        <?php echo $informativo['Informativo']['texto']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>                        

            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#c-slide" class="left carousel-control">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
        </a>
        <a id="nextInformativo" data-slide="next" href="#c-slide" class="right carousel-control">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

App Controller:

```
public $helpers = array(
        'Gravatar.Gravatar',
        'Html', 
        'Form', 
        'Session'
);

public $components = array(
        'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array('Saml.Saml')
        ),
        'Session',
        'Cookie');

var $uses = array('User');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();     

    $this->set('convertTime', $this->convertTime);

    if ($this->Saml){
        if ($this->Saml->isAuthenticated()) {               
            $infoWSO2 = $this->Saml->getAttributes();

            if($this->Session->read('UsuarioLogado') == NULL){
                 $userSistema = $this->User->atualizaSessao($infoWSO2);

                 $this->Session->write('UsuarioLogado', $userSistema);
            }

            $this->set('login_user', $infoWSO2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve fazer sua consulta no banco no AppController, mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
public function beforeRender() {

    // sua query
    $query = array(
        'order' => array(
            ...
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
            ...
        ),
        'recursive' => 1
    );

    $data = $this->SeuModel->find('all', $query);
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

Assim ele vai ficar disponível em todas as views.

Nao é uma pratica considerada correta, pois você vai ter essa consulta em todas seus controllers e actions, podendo futuramente causar uma certa lentidão na sua aplicação.

O mais correto, seria você salvar esses dados numa session, e consulta-la na view, assim não causaria impacto no banco de dados.

Comment: Na verdade é uma intranet interna da empresa, e esse item "informativos" é apenas um texto comum, o que não gerará lentidão.. Vou testar aqui e logo dou um retorno. Valeu

Comment: Então, à princípio está correto, porém na prática está dando erro.. Está dizendo que estou chamando a função find() em um não-objeto, porém quando capturo a variável criada através do var_dump, estão todas as informações na variável, está tudo certo.. Não sei o que pode ser..

Comment: Nao esqueça de declarar no seu app controler public $uses = array('SeuModel'); Fora do beforeRender. Faça isso e diga se deu certo. Espero ter ajudado :D

Comment: Já estou usando a variável $uses: var $uses = array('User'), como faço agora? Me desculpe, mas sou meio leigo em relação à isso..

Comment: Poste seu código por favor, assim fica mais fácil de identificar o problema. Edite sua pergunta, e coloque ele la.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta

Comment: Consegui fazer com base em sua ajuda, precisei apenas carregar o Model do informativos, valeu

Comment: Boa! Caso precise usar mais de um model no mesmo controller, basta adiciona-lo no array. var $uses = array('User','OutroModel','TerceiroModel');